# UIButton autoresizing on using AutoLayout on other elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

So, I'm using `NSLayoutConstraints` on different elements of my `UIViewController` but for some reason they're affecting my buttons. Like this :

[image: Screwed up buttons]

Here's my code :

```
// Twitter button
WelcomeButton *twitterButton = [[WelcomeButton alloc] initTwitterButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
twitterButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 350);
twitterButton.alpha = 1.0;
twitterButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[twitterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(twitterSignUpButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:twitterButton];

// Facebook button
WelcomeButton *facebookButton = [[WelcomeButton alloc] initFacebookButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
facebookButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 0);
facebookButton.alpha = 1.0;
facebookButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[facebookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookSignUpButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:facebookButton];

// Email Sign-Up button
WelcomeButton *emailButton = [[WelcomeButton alloc] initEmailButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
emailButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 0);
emailButton.alpha = 1.0;
emailButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[emailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(emailSignUpButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:emailButton];

// Signed-Up Message Label
UILabel *signedUpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
signedUpLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 25);
signedUpLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - (signedUpLabel.frame.size.width / 3) + 10, 0);
signedUpLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
signedUpLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:16];
signedUpLabel.text = @"Already Signed Up ?";
signedUpLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:signedUpLabel];

// Sign-In button
UIButton *signInButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
signInButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25);
signInButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + (signedUpLabel.frame.size.width / 3) + 10, 0);
signInButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
signInButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
[signInButton setTitle:@"Sign In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
signInButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
signInButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self.view addSubview:signInButton];
```

And here's my AutoLayout code :

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[signedUpLabel]-10-|"
                                                                                          options:0
                                                                                          metrics:0
                                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(signedUpLabel)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[signInButton]-2-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:0
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(signInButton)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[emailButton]-200-[signedUpLabel]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:0
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(emailButton, signedUpLabel)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[facebookButton]-100-[emailButton]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:0
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(facebookButton, emailButton)]];
```

What's going wrong here ?

I want these to be aligned together in a structure but why are they appearing like this ? When I haven't specified any constraints, they're appearing normally...

Comment: You didn't specify enough constraint (Here you specify only `Vertical Constraint`). I do this work in the `storyboard`... It's far away simpler.

Comment: I need to do it `programmatically`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `Horizontal Constraint`

If you want do it programmatically, maybe you could work with : https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

Edit : 
you can add an `Height Constraint` like :

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView(==60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myButton)]];
```

Comment: Even if I add a Horizontal Constraint, the `height` is decreased. Why ?

Comment: Did you try to add an `Height Constraint` like :
    `[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView(==60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myButton)]];`

Comment: Yup. Done that. Thanks. Just include that code snippet in your answer and I'll accept it...

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you use autolayout in xib?

Comment: If I could've, I would've.